# How can I center a splash image and text below that in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a splash screen looking like this. How can I change the XAML so that the image and the text are moved up.  Currently they are in the area surrounded by the red outline and I would like to move them up to the area surrounded by the blue outline?

[image]

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_image"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20.0dp" 
   />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtAppVersion"
    android:text="XXX"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100.0dp"/>
```

Comment: Try increasing the margin bottom value

Comment: Can I increase that for both the image and the text?  I would like to encapsulate those two in a frame and just increase margin bottom value once.

Comment: In that case put them both in a linear layout and apply margin-bottom to that linear layout by doing this you don't need to add a margin to individual items

Comment: Can you put that in as an answer using the code in the question surrounded but he layout and then I can accept that.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100.0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_image"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAppVersion"
        android:text="XXX"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

You can always increase the margin-bottom of that `linear layout` which is currently 100.00dp

Answer (score 0):

You can put both the ImageView and TextView in a vertical Linear Layout and use set the gravity to center. Then you can move the layout in vertical direction by using **android:translationY="-xxdp"**(Replace the xx with your value). Remember to put a '-' (minus) sign if you want to move it up.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:translationY="-xxdp">

      <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_image"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAppVersion"
        android:text="XXX"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps